# Specifying columns in Azure Log Analytics query

Tags: azure

In the Azure Kusto query system, I can add columns by manually typing them in using `project` :

```
AzureDiagnostics
| project TimeGenerated, httpMethod_s
```

or by selecting them with the "columns" button:

[image]

But when I select the columns I want visually, the query does not get updated and if I save the query, the choice of columns is not saved.

How can I update the query text to include the columns I've just selected?

Comment: You select/include columns with “project” (, which you already state so I don’t fully understand your problem/question? (Project Timegenerated,httpmethod_s,OperationName, Category

Comment: @Jarnstrom If I adjust the list of columns using the visual selector, the query text does not get updated. Is there any way to update the query to match what has been selected?

Comment: It's a microsoft product.  The behavior you describe, Glen, would be intuitive.  The two will never match

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify the columns you want in the query, like I have done on the last line below.

```
[AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider =="MICROSOFT.DBFORPOSTGRESQL" 
| where Category == "PostgreSQLLogs"
and not (Message contains "connection")
and not (Message contains "does not exist") 
 | sort by TimeGenerated desc
 | project TimeGenerated, Message
```